# How to recognize layout by sending view as a parameter?

Tags: android, view

I am sending view as a parameter. So in private method somehow I need to recognize which view I received. Could you please let me know how to do that.

I have searched on stack and all solutions are based on tag or inflator. Which generates more code in my case.

Thank you

Comment: You can use `View.getId()` to return your view's identifier.

Comment: @BenShmuel no its returning the number but not that Id which I put in xml. That was first what I tried. But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in Android have an [id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) and tags, you could use either to identify which view you passed.

If that is not what you are after, can you explain in more details what you are trying to do?

Comment: someView.getId() == R.id.some_id_in_xml

Comment: no you cant compare getId with R.id.something. because getId() returning some generic number

Comment: as nobody could provide how to recognize by id you can edit your answer that only tag could help to recognize and there is no way to recognize by id. And ill mark it as a right answer

Comment: That is incorrect, the R generated file would have that same id value of the view if you did declare it in the xml.

Scenario: 
1- Define an xml layout file and add a view with id
2- Build your project to generate the R file
3- In your Activity code `someView.getId() == R.id.some_id_in_xml`

Comment: Ok ok. Now I got what happenes. I tried for example call `mSubmitBtn.getId()' I received as id 2131230060. and you cant call `toString()` for that. But at the same time YES you can compare it to id. So somehow `R.id.some_id` it transfer to the number. That was blind spot for me. I thought it suppose to return me id like `some_id_in_xml` but not number